# After upgrading to El Capitan, Preview opens the sidebar. How can I permanently disable it without having coding skills?

Tags: macos, preview

After upgrading to El Capitan, Preview opens the sidebar. How can I permanently disable it without having coding skills? I saw other answers to this annoying problem, but I don't have the capacity to do it and don't want to mess up my computer trying it. Is there an alternative?

Answer (score 1):

This should work. Type the following in `Terminal`:

```
cd ~/Library/Containers/com.apple.Preview/Data/Library/Preferences/

defaults write com.apple.Preview PVPDFSuppressSidebarOnOpening true
```